# Eclipse, Less, Formatter: How to disable space between ! and "important"

Tags: css, eclipse, less

In my less file I have for example "margin: 0px !important;" when I run the formatter it produces "margin: 0px ! important;" which produces a validation error in the generated CSS file.

Can anybody help how to configure to ignore the validation error or change the formatter to not add a space between quote sign and "important"?

**UPDATE**:

As Kheema Pandey pointed I should paste a code snippet.

Before Formatting:

```
div.text {
  margin: 0px !important;
}
```

After Formatting:

```
div.text {
  margin: 0px ! important;
}
```

Comment: Sir, please post a code..

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to file a bug report with the maintainers of Eclipse.